# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n} \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+2a}} + \cdots + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+na}}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation, infinity

> Find
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n} \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+a}}  + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+2a}} + \cdots + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+na}}\right)$$

What I have done by now to answer:

First I did a little bit of programming to figure out what the answer is maybe it give me a sense of what I should do
I arrived at $2(\sqrt{a+1} - 1).$

And the other thing that come to my mind is that difference between each term of summation is about $0$ and as there are infinite terms I can write the summation as an integral of square root function between $1/(a+1)$ and $1$.

Comment: You should add your attempts so far and where you get stuck. Otherwise your question is likely to get closed. For math formulas see here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What about the question that you don't have any clue about the answer?

Comment: By the way I did just a little bit of few things and I mentioned it.

Comment: @Erfan Do you know how to convert summation into definte integral(riemann sum)?

Comment: Looks like a Riemann Sum

Comment: @RamanujanXV 
No. I'm just a high school student passionate about math. can you give me a reference on how to do it maybe I can figure the question out by my own.

Comment: @Erfan No problem.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum you can read about it here and also see a few illustrations on youtube (https://youtu.be/pAtSgEhGCs8) you will get it..

Comment: It's the Riemann sum : $$\dfrac{a}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1 + a \dfrac{k}{n}}}$$

Comment: [This is really similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091343/interpreting-riemann-sums-as-integrals?noredirect=1), but not a duplicate, in my opinion. It's a special case and I cannot find the general case anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\displaystyle \frac{a}{n} \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+a}}  + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+2a}} + \cdots + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+na}}\right) & = & \displaystyle \dfrac{a}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a \dfrac{k}{n}}} \\[5mm]
& \to & \displaystyle a \int_0^1 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1 + a x}} \\[5mm]
& = & \displaystyle 2 \left[\sqrt{1 + a x}\right]_0^1 \\[5mm]
& = & 2 \sqrt{1 + a} - 2
\end{array}$$